# Unexpected behavior of reduce when merging large dataframes from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, reduce

I have a dictionary of 21 dataframes (called paramdic), each of which has two columns ('ID' and then a unique something else) and around 12,000 rows. I'm trying to merge them all together to make a single df which is around 12,000 rows and 22 columns, ID and then all the something elses (a, b, c, etc). The IDs are all unique, though not every dataframe has a given ID, the overlap is pretty good. I'm doing this:

```
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['ID'],
                                            how='outer'), paramdic.values())
```

But it gives me a dataframe with 22 columns and over 76 million rows. If I do this with only a subset of the data (say, 2500 rows and 21 dataframes) it works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do some more debugging, put it in a loop and check and see how the rows grow. How many unique IDs are there in total?

Comment: There are 14936 unique IDs. I started adding them together one by one using: 'm1=pd.merge(paramdic['A'], paramdic['B'], on='ID', 
                    how='outer')' and then adding the next parameter manually, and the number of rows quickly exceeds 14936, even though the number of unique ID's ends up being the expected 14936. Looks like having ID as the key to merge on is occasionally ending up in a new row being created instead of being tacked on to the existing row, still not sure why it is happening.

Comment: How are you counting unique IDs? There may be something like a datatype mis-match, strings versus ints or whatever.

Comment: The unique IDs are strings, TN-MW-1, TX-MW-2, TN-MW-3, etc, and I'm using df.ID.unique() and then checking the size to count them. I think there must be something about how merge works that I'm misunderstanding that is causing it to create these duplicates and partial duplicates instead of just having everything added to the existing unique ID row.